# IIS 6.0 stopped unexpectedly

Tags: windows, iis-6, plesk

I'm running those web sites on Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition SP2 .However,I'm having a IIS problem for a last 3 days.IIS stopped unexpectedly.
I can't find somehow a problem.Also,it doesn't appear any `w3wp.exe` process in the task manager.I'm running `iisreset` command.it's not working.But,I restarted web server,it's working.

System: Windows Server 2003 EnterPrise Editon SP2 / IIS 6 and Plesk Panel 8.2

What's the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is IIS stay up and running or does it crash after few minutes? You should look at eventviewer event logs to get additional info. Could be a bad ISAPI filter or CGI that's causing it to crash on load. Evenviewer should give some details on when and what crashed it.